# Multithreading UI status logging

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a multithreaded windows form application where I'd like to add UI logging option to display the thread activity in a textbox or other UI control.

Currently I am able to display the logs of all threads in a textbox using a delegate in the main form.

I am looking for a way to display only one thread's log at a time(this is based on user selecting the datagridview row corresponding to the thread) and as well updated continuously as the thread still runs in the background with new logs updated.

Ideally I want to use a single textbox to change the content of it based on user selection.

Say, When the user clicks row 3 of grid, the textbox would clear any previous content and changed with the logs of thread t3 and continues to update them real time.

Please suggest me the ways of doing it, even if it uses different control other than textbox. Any help is highly appreciated.

PS: Just to make it clear, the textbox isn't part of the DataGridView. It should be a status logger outside of the DGV.

Comment: Firstly, ask your user what a thread is. Unless he can answer you what a thread is...you are doing something very very wrong. The user only cares about "Units of work" or "Processes". Also, there should be no reason you need a thread for each unit of work. In fact there should be no reason you should need more than a single thread (most likely).

Comment: Same as @Aron, I don't see why it is *multithreading*  in any way. User has to be introduced to concept of *job* in your application (if there are multiple jobs running simultaneously and you want to display progress from only one, selected by user). Your delegate will need some kind of *identification* (job id), then you store last (or all) message from that id in some list and switch to this list display if user choose to display job with this id. Doesn't sounds/looks very hard or requiring architecturing. So what is the problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In this case, users sees datagridview where each row does some task asynchronously via a thread. t1 corresponds to the task of the row 1 of DGV. When the user clicks on a particular row, the logs of only that particular thread should be displayed in a text box. Likewise, when a different row is selected, textbox should clear the data and show the data corresponding to the new row. Main issue is to update the textbox with messages in real time until the thread itself exits. hope it's clear.

Comment: Why don't use a listview instead? A virtualized one that asks for items to show would work.

Comment: @Sinatr edited the OP to state the textbox is outside of DGV.

Comment: Even if in another window, it doesn't matter. Your DGV has [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx), in that event you change *job id* which log (last message?) has to be displayed in textbox and redraw textbox content. What is the problem?

Comment: @Sinatr I know to handle the event of the dgv and update the textbox content if it is static or up to the last message which is saved. But what I want is when I select a particular row, from then onwards the textbox should get updated continuously with the logs of that thread.

Comment: Ok, all threads should call some logger, e.g `Log(string threadID, string message, ...)`. They should supply *id* together with each message, that id is currently selected item in DGV (you could make a hidden column to store it, or use index or store it as a `Tag`, whatever). When user change DGV selection - new id is set for logger, textbox is update for that thread id. I repeat, at which steps you have problems? You don't understand concept/necessity of id? You want id to be something different? You don't know how to make class with event and subscribe to it to update textbox(with `Invoke`)?

Comment: @Sinatr ok, currently I use Action delegate to update the textbox content whenever there's a update in any of the threads, so it's real time. Now I don't know how to make the textbox pick/set the right thread's log when the DGV row selection is changed. When it's done the textbox should be updated in real time for that thread's activity.

Comment: Can you post that part of code (where you update textbox)? *Real time* doesn't change anything. If your problem is to change textbox value immediately when user select DGV item, then all you have to do is to **memorize last message for each thread**. `Dictionary<string, string>` (id, mesage) may do.

Comment: writeToLog = delegate(string s)
            {
                if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    var text = new Addlog(this.LoadLogTextBoxCallBack);
                    this.Invoke(text, new object[] { s });
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}    {2}{3}",Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now, s, this.textBox1.Text);
                }

This writeToLog object is in mainform, it's passed as parameter to each thread. So for every new action, it will append the text to textbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70035/discussion-between-questions-and-sinatr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
writeToLog = delegate(string s)
{
    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var text = new Addlog(this.LoadLogTextBoxCallBack);
        this.Invoke(text, new object[] { s });
    }
    else
        this.textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}{1} {2}{3}",Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now, s, this.textBox1.Text);
}
```

You need 2 methods:

```
Dictionary<string, string> _log = new Dictionary<string, string>();

void UpdateTextBox(string id)
{
    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(UpdateTextBox, new object[] { id });
    else
        textBox1.Text = _log[id];
}

void AddToLog(string id, string message)
{
    // add new or update
    if(_log.ContainsKey(id))
        _log[id] = string.Format("{0}{1} {2}{3}", Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now, message, _log[id]);
    else
        _log.Add(id, string.Format("{0}{1} {2}", Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now, message);
    UpdateTextBox(id);
}
```

You call `AddToLog()` from your threads and `UpdateTextBox` from DGV selected changed event.

There are a lot of improvements (thread-safety? dictionary initializaiton, store id). I leave them to you. If it would be me, then there would be a `Log` class with `Add()` method and `Added` event, should make it more oop-ish.